# android findViewById is null in LinearLayout

Tags: java, android

android findViewById method return value is null

this view is custom class

view.xml

```
<include
        android:id="@+id/view_before_login"
        layout="@layout/view_mypage_before_login"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

view activity java (Fragment)

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.view, container, false);

        mBefore = (MemberBeforeLoginView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.view_before_login);
        mAfter = (MemberAfterLoginView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.view_after_login);

        mBefore.SetStateListener(this);
        mAfter.SetStateListener(this);

        route();

        return rootView;
    }
```

inside xml is view_mypage_before_login.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.main.view.MemberAfterLoginView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/profile"
        android:layout_width="137dp"
        android:layout_height="121dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/empty" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/logout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="logout" />
</com.main.view.MemberAfterLoginView>
```

com.main.view.MemberAfterLoginView.java

```
public class MemberAfterLoginView extends LinearLayout implements View.OnClickListener, MemberViewListener.MemberChildViewInterface {
    private MemberViewListener mMemberListener = null;

    private Button mBtnLogout = null;

    public MemberAfterLoginView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        initialize(context);
    }

    public MemberAfterLoginView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        initialize(context);
    }

    public MemberAfterLoginView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        initialize(context);
    }

    private void initialize(Context context) {
        /*LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_mypage_after_login, null);
        */

        mBtnLogout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.logout);
    }
...
```

why null variable mBtnLogout ? (initialize function inside variable)

I am immature in English.
Sorry.

Comment: where are you bind your XML in class??

Comment: Remove the comment from `LayoutInflater `.

Comment: If  specify a class name in xml, is not it bound?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private View initialize(Context context) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_mypage_after_login, null);

    mBtnLogout = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.logout);
    return v;
}
```

The button is part of new inflated view. since the inflate result is not applied to the activity yet `activity.findViewById` cannot find it.

Answer (score 1):

You had inflater in comment line. Remove that from comment line

Answer (score 0):

```
/*LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_mypage_after_login, null);
        */
```

Un comment this line

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MemberAfterLoginView extends LinearLayout {

    private ImageView mBtnLogout;

    public MemberAfterLoginView(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public MemberAfterLoginView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public MemberAfterLoginView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);

        init(attrs);
    }

    private void init(AttributeSet attrs) {
        LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.view_mypage_after_login, this, true);

        mBtnLogout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.logout);
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the following changes in your `init(AttributeSet attrs)` method

```
View view = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.view_mypage_after_login, this, true);

mBtnLogout = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.logout);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the child views in `onViewAdded`. If you already defined your child views in Layout.

```
@Override
public void onViewAdded(View child) {
    super.onViewAdded(child);

    switch (child.getId()) {
        case R.id.profile:
            Log.d("", "addView: profile Added");
            break;
        case R.id.logout:
            ((Button)child).setText("New alue");
            break;
    }
}
```